# d3 append multiple elements as siblings

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got a force-directed graph with labels on the nodes. In order to keep everything organized, I am keeping each circle/label pair inside a `<g>` element.

The tricky part is that on a doubleclick of the node, I am adding more points to the graph, and running this function again - what that means is that I start getting duplicate text elements.

Is there a way to put the `append("text")` inside the same `enter()` scope but make it append as a sibling of the `circle` instead of as a child?

I looked at this answer, which helpd me understand what I should be doing, but I don't know how to get both appends to be siblings... 
[D3js force duplicate nodes on enter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984603/d3js-force-duplicate-nodes-on-enter)

```
            node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(drag)
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return publisherScale(d.publisher);
                })
                .style("stroke", "rgba(255,255,255,.8)");

            node.append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("dx", 10)
                .style("font-size", nominal_text_size + "px")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return '\u2002' + d.name
                });
```

Comment: `var g = node.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'node'); g.append('circle'); g.append('text');`

Comment: Thank you - I don't know why that one didn't show up when I searched.